# CasperJS: WaitFor timeout function to do rescroll?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I met some problem when I use CasperJS to scrape a website. The website is dynamically loaded like Twitter, so I want to do infinite scroll,
and thanks to @Artjom B. I found you code to do this.

```
var tryAndScroll = function (casper) {
    try {
        casper.echo('SCROLL!!');
        casper.scrollToBottom();

        if (casper.exists('div.loading')) {
            var curItems = casper.evaluate(getCurrentInfosNum);
            casper.echo(curItems);
            casper.waitFor(function check() {
                return curItems != casper.evaluate(getCurrentInfosNum);
            }, function then() {
                casper.wait(800);
                tryAndScroll(casper);
            }, function onTimeout() {
                casper.emit('scroll.timeout',curItems);
            }, 15000);
        } else {
            casper.echo("No more items");
            return true;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        casper.echo(err);
    }
} //casper.tryAndScroll
```

And now, I want to continue to scroll many times when the timeout function invoked so I create my own event listener,‘scroll.timeout’.

```
var SRCOLL_NUM = 0;
var PreOfLoaded = 0;
casper.on('scroll.timeout', function (NumOfLoaded) {
    if (SRCOLL_NUM <= 4) {
        if (PreOfLoaded == NumOfLoaded)
            SRCOLL_NUM++;
        this.echo("Scroll Timeout,reScroll");
        PreOfLoaded = NumOfLoaded;
        tryAndScroll(casper);
    } else {
        this.echo("Scroll Timeout,reScroll times maximum");
        SRCOLL_NUM = 0;
        PreOfLoaded = 0;
    }
});
```

However, when scroll timeout occurred, it printed `Scroll Timeout,reScroll` on the console. Then it skips `tryAndScroll()` and go to the next step in the main function. I want to continue to next step after retry scroll many times. What should I do?

I found CasperJS author illustrate :[Automatic retry when open fails](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/311)

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.tryOpen = function(url, then) {
return this.then(function() {
    this.open(url);
    this.waitFor(function testStatus() {
        return this.getCurrentHTTPStatus === 200;
    }, then, function onFail() {
        console.log('failed, retrying');
        this.tryOpen(url);
    }, 2000);
});
};

casper.start().tryOpen('http://failing.url.com/foo.bar', function() {
this.echo('wow, it worked, wtf');
}).run();
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return this.currentHTTPStatus === 200;
```

I tested with the newest version of casperjs 1.1.1, it's working fine